# Convert Excel value from code page 1251 to unicode

Tags: python, excel, unicode

I'm accesing an Excel thru python to adjust some encoding of the cells. My code so far:

```
from xlrd import *
from xlwt import *

wb = open_workbook('a.xls')

s = wb.sheets()[0]

for row in range(s.nrows):
e = s.cell(row,9).value
r = s.cell(row,11).value
print e,' ',r.decode('cp1251')
```

When running this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pem\workspace\a\src\a.py", line 17, in <module>
    print e,' ',r.decode('cp1251')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 23: character maps to <undefined>
```

I know that **e** is english text and **r** is the russian translation in 1251 encoding.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Python 2. *(Unicode handling is different in Python 3.)*

Use `r.decode('cp1252')` to decode `r` in your encoding into unicode. This will give you an object of type `unicode`.

Note that if you try to print it, it will be first implicitly encoded, i.e. converted back to `str` with default encoding `ansi`. If your console supports unicode, you can print it by saying:

```
print xyz.encode('utf-8')
```

---

Note that Python's `str` string consists of 8-bit bytes (characters), while `unicode` represents an actual string where one character can be any unicode character. *(In Python 3, `str` was replaced by `bytes` and `unicode` renamed to `str` to make this more obvious.)*

`.decode()` on a `str` allows you to get a "meaningful" unicode string out of some bytes (that you read from somewhere) using an encoding you specify, while `.decode()` on an `unicode` object does the opposite: allows you to get the byte representation of a string using an encoding of your choice.

Comment: @PeterMmm: you still get errors because you still have not `encode()`ed your data; you must ***both*** decode from cp1251 to `unicode` and the encode from unicode to utf-8

Comment: @TokenMacGuy is right, let me just emphasize that that final .encode('utf-8') is only for the sake of `print` and your console; your application itself may be fine with using the `unicode` object itself as returned from `decode`.